# A two dimensions numpy array cannot be displayed correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a two dimensions numpy array, difference of some values are small, but large for other values, for example:

```
[[0.66667, 0.66675, 0.66725, ... , 0.66634], 
 [0.66377, 0.66634, 0.66280, ... , 0.66172],
                      ...                  ,
 [0.0,     0.0,     0.66536, ... , 0.65523],
 [0.0,     0.0,     0.65231, ... , 0.66723]] = M
```

I tried `plt.imshow()` , and use `vmin` `vmax` to control colorbar, but it still cannot display correctly.

[image: Incorrect picture]

My code:

```
def MinMax(M):
    NZM = M.nonzero()
    bmin =M[NZM].min()
    bmax = M.max()
    bmax, bmin = format(bmax, '.5f'), format(bmin, '.5f')
    bmax = bmax + str(0.00001)
    bmin = bmin + str(0.00001)
    return bmax, bmin

cmax, cmin = MinMax(M)
plt.imshow(M, origin="lower", vmin=cmin, vmax=cmax)
```

I want to get picture like:

[image: bottom right is zero value area]

Attachment:
I tried normalize this array then draw it but this will cause some unknow problem and picture drawed incorrectly. Furthermore some data related problem also let me not to try to normalize data.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot display correctly"? Do you get an error? Do it look different than expected?

Comment: I uploaded incorrect picture @Brian61354270

Comment: `bmax = bmax + str(0.00001)` -- string concatenation to determine minimum and maximum?

Comment: What is the shape of `M`? And why are the min and max strings? There's probably some weird promotion to `<U` going on.

Comment: I also tried setting float params manually, but still incorrect

Comment: Wait a minute, I need to edit my post.

Comment: If I use `bmax = bmax + 0.00001` directly it will be error: "can only concatenate str (not "float") to str", I don't know why :( , isn't these two are floats? @DanMašek

Comment: @WinertozBotawar We don't know how you create `M` so we can't answer you.

Comment: Sorry I just found bmax is a string type value

Comment: Yes, you turned the floats into strings on the line preceding that, by calling `format`.

Comment: It's a large process, I can only provide its result (I don't know where to upload my file) @Guimoute

Comment: Thank you all guys, I think I got right result

Comment: To be fair it's incomprehensible that `imshow` does not raise a `TypeError` when you provide a string as `vmin` or `vmax`, especially when `vmax` is something like `"0.667250.00001"` with two dots.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure, you did not want to have bmin = bmin + str(0.00001) (and the same for bmax). It is exactly the same as bmin /= 100_000 and it is why you only have 2 colors: 0's and non-zeros.